# Difference in Function typing in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell

I've been playing around with basic functions in Haskell, and am a little confused with the difference between the following type declarations for the function `f`

```
f :: Integer -> Integer
```

versus

```
f :: Integral n => n -> n
```

So far, I've treated both of these as identical, but I'm sure this isn't true. What is the difference?

**Edit:** As a response to the first answer, I wanna propose a similar example which more is along the lines of the question I hold.

Consider the following declarations

```
f :: Num n => n -> n
```

or

```
f :: Num -> Num
```

What functionality does each offer?

Comment: It should be `f :: Integral n => n -> n` such that the type variable `n` represents multiple types which are members of the `Integral` type class.

Comment: Re: your edit: The first declaration offers the functionality of working at all.  The second does not.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Oops my bad, I just don't get this yet at all. I'll read through the answers and hopefully I'll understand!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's rename:

```
f :: Integer -> Integer
g :: (Integral n) => n -> n
```

I like to follow a fairly common practice of adding parentheses to the constraint section of the signature.  It helps it stand out as different.

`f :: Integer -> Integer` is simple, it takes an integer and returns another integer.

As for `g :: (Integral n) => n -> n`: `Integral` is not a type itself, rather it's more like a predicate. Some types are `Integral`, others aren't.  For example, `Int` is an `Integral` type, `Double` is not.

Here `n` is a *type variable*, and it can refer to any type.  `(Integral n)` is a *constraint* on the type variable, which restricts what types it can refer to.  So you could read it like this:

> `g` takes a value of *any type* `n` and returns a value of *that same type*, provided that it is an `Integral` type.

If we examine the `Integral` typeclass:

```
ghci> :info Integral
class (Real a, Enum a) => Integral a where
  quot :: a -> a -> a
  rem :: a -> a -> a
  div :: a -> a -> a
  mod :: a -> a -> a
  quotRem :: a -> a -> (a, a)
  divMod :: a -> a -> (a, a)
  toInteger :: a -> Integer
 {-# MINIMAL quotRem, toInteger #-}
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Integral Word -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Integral Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Integral Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
```

We can see 3 builtin types which are `Integral`. Which means that `g` *simultaneously* has three different types, depending on how it is used.

```
g :: Word -> Word
g :: Integer -> Integer
g :: Int -> Int
```

(And if you define another `Integral` type in the future, `g` will automatically work with that as well)

The `Word -> Word` variant is a good example, since `Word`s cannot be negative.  `g`, when given a positive machine-sized number, returns another positive machine-sized number, whereas `f` could return any integer, including negative ones or gigantic ones.

`Integral` is a rather specific class.  It's easier to see with `Num`, which has fewer methods and thus can represent more types:

```
h :: (Num a) => a -> a
```

This is also a generalization of `f`, that is, you could use `h` where something with `f`'s type is expected.  But `h` can also take a complex number, and it would then return a complex number.

The key with signatures like `g`'s and `h`'s is that they work on multiple types, as long as the return type is the same as the input type.

Comment: Perfect! This makes a lot more sense now!

Answer (score 4):

According to this [link](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/numbers.html) the standard instances of the `Integral` type class are `Integer` and `Int`. `Integer` is a primitive type, and it acts like an unbounded mathematical integer. So given:

```
f :: Integral n => n -> n
```

`n` could be `Int` or `Integer` or any "custom" type that you define that is an `instance` of `Integral`. The use of type classes allows for type polymorphism.

`f :: Num -> Num` **WILL NOT COMPILE** because `Num` is **not** a type. `Num` has kind `* -> Constraint` and is thus a **type constructor** whereas `f` requires an ordinary **type** or **monotype** which has kind `*`, such as `Int` or `Integer` (also known as type system primitives). See the haskell wiki for a brief reference/jumping off point about [kinds](https://wiki.haskell.org/Kind). Haskell has a rich type system with higher-order types, if used correctly it can be an extremely powerful tool i.e. type polymorphism.

Comment: maybe stress that `f :: Num -> Num` is simply invalid, as `Num` is not a type.

Comment: `Num :: * -> Constraint`, not `* -> *`

Comment: thanks for the editing, and by the way very good answer, plus one!

Answer (score 2):

```
f :: Integer -> Integer
```

`f` is a function from arbitrary sized integers to arbitrary sized integers.

```
f' :: Integral n => n -> n
```

`f'` is a **polymorphic** function from type `n` to type `n`. Any type `n` that is member of the class `Integral` is allowed. Examples for types in `Integral` are `Integer` and `Int` (the integer type with fixed precision).

```
f'' :: Num n => n -> n
```

`f''` is also a **polymorphic** function, but this time for class `Num`. `Num` is a more generic number type that has more members than `Integral`, but all types in `Integral` are also in contained in `Num`. For `f''` `n` can also be `Double`.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

`f :: Integer -> Integer` works for one type: `Integer`.

`f :: Integral n => n -> n` works for `Integer`, `Int`, `Word`, `Int32`, `Int64`, `Word8`, and any arbitrary user-defined types that implement the `Integral` type class.

That's the short version. If you only care about one type, it's easier to type-check and more efficient to execute if you specify that one type. If you *want* multiple types, then the second way is probably the way to do.

Comment: “more efficient to execute” – actually, GHC will in many of the important cases specialise a polymorphic function to the concrete type it's used with. If you use an `Integral n => n -> n` function with `Int`, it will typically run _faster_ than a monomorphic `Integer -> Integer` version.